# How to get a cookie form a specific subdomain with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

In Ruby on Rails, you can delete and set cookies with options in a hash, such as `:domain` that you could change to `sub.domain.com` instead of `.domain.com` to get some control of your subdomain cookies.

I'm working on a SPA that set cookies from the front-end and the domain it's set on is `app.domain.com` and it'd be kind of tricky to change the mechanism here. The Rails app needs to read one of the cookies on `.domain.com` so, of course, it returns `nil`

Is there any way in Rails to get the value of a cookie from a subdomain? I've looked throughout the documentation and public methods from `cookies` itself and couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible without changing how the cookie is set.

When setting a cookie without explicitly setting a domain, then the browser will only send the cookie to the exact same domain, not even to subdomains of that domain. This is a security feature implemented in the browser and, of course, the application has no way to access cookies that are not sent by the browser with the request to the server.

When setting a cookie with an explicit domain (for example `sub.domain.com`), then the cookie will be shared with that domain **and all subdomains of that domain** (like `foo.sub.domain.com`). But it is still not shared with the parent domain.

The only way to make it work, would be to set the cookie explicitly to `domain.com` which would tell the browser to share this cookie with `domain.com`, but also with **all subdomains**, like `sub.domain.com`, `foo.sub.domain.com`, or `sub2.domain.com`.

**Note:** Sharing the cookie across all subdomains can have serious security implications depending on what your cookie is used for – especially when some of your subdomains are not fully controlled by yourselves, but by third parties. For example, if you shared a session token that way and had a third party SaaS product configured to use one of your subdomains, then the session token would be shared with that third party tool.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll opt for another strategy and set it to the root domain then.